# How to inject the "tags" property inside the Message Resource JSON payload of a message sent via Twilio API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to have a unique idenfitier for a message I am sending through Twilio Studio and Serverless Functions. However, I am having trouble with adding a new property to the JSON payload. I was perusing the documentation and found a JSON payload which has the "tags" property (see photo below). Does anyone have an idea on how they added the "tags" property? Thanks in advance.

[Image of the "tags" property inside the JSON Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6Qx.png)

I have tried adding data via the Advanced Configuration section of the send message node, however those properties do not show up in the JSON payload when I execute the GET Request. I have also tried using the .update function when accessing a specific message, however, this function can only be used to redact the body string. Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: The tags you see are related to a private beta called [Message Tagging](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/messaging-for-marketing#:~:text=Message%20Tagging%20enables%20marketers%20to,box%2C%20reporting%20of%20engagement%20metrics.). However, I'm not sure whether they would help with your use-case as they cannot identify a single message resource. Can you elaborate on why you would like a unique identifier and why the message SID doesn't work for you?